# How to display the number of objects in an image for single class?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, single-shot-detector

I am new to programming and been learning the tutorial in google colab for algorithm in object detection. Below is the code used in google object detection API https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb , it using single shot detector to output images. I added a global variable "count" and for loop to count the number of objects with score more than 0.5. This will work in the case for single class detection. Checked the result with several images and it's printed the count value correctly as in this [Number of dogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAk9o.jpg). Now, I want to display this number on images. As an example, in the images it added a row, "Number of people: {count value}" Please show me how to edit the code below to achieve the result.

```
 def show_inference(model, image_path):
  global count
  count=0
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare 
  the result image with boxes and labels on it.       
  image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
   # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
  image_np,
  output_dict['detection_boxes'],
  output_dict['detection_classes'],
  output_dict['detection_scores'],
  category_index,
  instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
  line_thickness=8)
  display(Image.fromarray(image_np))
  for o in output_dict['detection_scores']:
   if o > 0.5:
   count=count+1
 print(count)
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
 show_inference(detection_model, image_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, create boxes to count numbers you can do this easily by this example I use for object counters AI number counts.

Sample: Using basics boundary boxes with colors from Tensorflow, AI applications applied the same you can use YOLO or any NN.
It as Bitmap drawing FN, you need to create an image over another image you can make it a collaboration.

```
def search_screen( image_cropped ):
    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( image_cropped )
    image_cropped = tf.cast( image_cropped, dtype=tf.float32 )
    width = image_cropped.shape[1]
    height = image_cropped.shape[0]
    channels = image_cropped.shape[2]
    box_sizes = 10
    n_boxes = 10
    
    object_position = [ 0, 0, 0 ]
    object_properties = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    object_count = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    
    global list_input_data
    global list_position_data
    global list_label
    global scores
    
    list_input_data = tf.zeros([ 1, 21, 21, 3 ]).numpy()
    list_position_data = tf.zeros([ 1, 3 ]).numpy()
    list_label = tf.zeros([ 1, 1 ]).numpy()
    
    list_input_data = list_input_data[-100:,-2100:,-2100:,-300:]
    list_input_data = tf.cast( list_input_data, dtype=tf.float32 ).numpy()
    list_position_data = list_position_data[-100:,-300:]
    list_position_data = tf.cast( list_position_data, dtype=tf.float32 ).numpy()
    list_label = list_label[-100:,-100:]
    list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.float32 ).numpy()
    
    global i_count
    
    for i in range(n_boxes):
        for j in range(n_boxes):
            cropped_image_cell_search = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image_cropped, int( CROP_SIZE[0] / 10 ) * i, 
                    int( CROP_SIZE[1] / 10 ) * j, int( CROP_SIZE[0] / 10 ), int( CROP_SIZE[1] / 10 ) )
            
            
            
            left_to_right = tf.image.flip_left_right(cropped_image_cell_search)
            up_to_down = tf.image.flip_up_down(cropped_image_cell_search)
            
            left_to_right = tf.math.count_nonzero( cropped_image_cell_search - left_to_right, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64 ).numpy()
            
            if left_to_right == 0 :
                pass

            else :
            
                up_to_down = tf.math.count_nonzero( cropped_image_cell_search - up_to_down, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64 ).numpy()
                
                a_rot = tf.image.rot90( cropped_image_cell_search )
                a_rot = tf.constant( a_rot, shape=( 16, 21, 3) )
                picture_temp = tf.constant( cropped_image_cell_search, shape=( 21, 16, 3 ) )
                a_rot = tf.concat([ tf.zeros([ 5, 21, 3]), a_rot], axis=0 )
                b_rot = tf.concat([ picture_temp, tf.zeros([ 21, 5, 3])], axis=1 )
                diag = tf.math.count_nonzero( tf.math.subtract( a_rot, b_rot, name='subtract' ) ).numpy()
                
                if ( diag <= 565 and diag >= 500 and up_to_down <= 96 and left_to_right >= 70 and left_to_right <= 100 ):
                
                    object_position[0] = i * height
                    object_position[1] = j * width
                    object_properties = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
                    object_properties[0] = left_to_right
                    object_properties[1] = up_to_down
                    object_properties[2] = diag
                    object_properties[3] = 1
                    object_properties[4] = 1
                    
                    target_object = 9
                    prediction_scores = tf.ones( [ n_objects ] ) * 95.00
                    
                    object_properties = tf.constant( object_properties, shape=( 5, 1, 1 ), dtype=tf.float32 )
                    object_properties = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling1D( size=63 )( object_properties )
                    object_properties = tf.constant( object_properties, shape=( 21, 5, 3 ) )
                    input_data = tf.squeeze( cropped_image_cell_search )
                    input_data = tf.concat( [input_data, object_properties], axis=1 )
                    label = tf.constant( 9, dtype=tf.int64 ).numpy()
                    
                    list_input_data = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_input_data, tf.constant( input_data, shape=(1, 21, 21, 3)), axis=0 )
                    list_position_data = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_position_data, tf.constant( object_position, shape=(1, 3)), axis=0 )
                    list_label = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_label, tf.constant( label, shape=(1, 1)), axis=0 )
                
                    Y_scope = float(( int( height / n_boxes ) * i ) / height )
                    Y_alise = float(( int( height / n_boxes ) * ( i + 1 ) ) / height )
                    X_scope = float(( int( width / n_boxes ) * j ) / width )
                    X_alise = float(( int( width / n_boxes ) * ( j + 1 ) ) / width )
                    boxes_custom_input = tf.constant([ Y_scope, X_scope, Y_alise, X_alise ], shape=(1, 1, 4))
                    colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
                    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( tf.squeeze(image_cropped) / 256.0 )
                    image_cropped = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(tf.constant(image_cropped, shape=(1, IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1], IMAGE_SIZE[2]), dtype=tf.float32), boxes_custom_input, colors)
                    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( tf.squeeze(image_cropped) *  255.0 )
                
                
                elif ( left_to_right > 130 and up_to_down > 130 and diag > 600  ) :
                    i_count = i_count + 1
                    object_position[0] = i * height
                    object_position[1] = j * width
                    object_properties = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
                    object_properties[0] = left_to_right
                    object_properties[1] = up_to_down
                    object_properties[2] = diag
                    object_properties[3] = 1
                    object_properties[4] = 1
                    
                    if b_save_image_object :
                        file = "F:\\temp\\image_catagorize\\20220620\\{filename_1:n}_{filename_2:n}".format(filename_1 = i_count, filename_2 = diag) + ".png"
                        tf.keras.utils.save_img(
                                file, cropped_image_cell_search, data_format=None, file_format=None, scale=True )
                
                    target_object, prediction_scores, input_data, label = identity_target_objects( cropped_image_cell_search, object_position, object_properties, n_boxes * i + j )
                    list_input_data = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_input_data, tf.constant( input_data, shape=(1, 21, 21, 3)), axis=0 )
                    list_position_data = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_position_data, tf.constant( object_position, shape=(1, 3)), axis=0 )
                    list_label = tf.experimental.numpy.append( list_label, tf.constant( label, shape=(1, 1)), axis=0 )
                    
                    temp = int(object_count[target_object])
                    object_count[target_object] = temp + 1
                    
                    Y_scope = float(( int( height / n_boxes ) * i ) / height )
                    Y_alise = float(( int( height / n_boxes ) * ( i + 1 ) ) / height )
                    X_scope = float(( int( width / n_boxes ) * j ) / width )
                    X_alise = float(( int( width / n_boxes ) * ( j + 1 ) ) / width )
                    boxes_custom_input = tf.constant([ Y_scope, X_scope, Y_alise, X_alise ], shape=(1, 1, 4))
                    
                    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( tf.squeeze(image_cropped) / 256.0 )
                    
                    colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
                    
                    if target_object == 0:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
                    elif target_object == 1:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.5, 0.5]])
                    elif target_object == 2:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]])
                    elif target_object == 3:
                        colors = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
                    elif target_object == 4:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.5, 0.0]])
                    elif target_object == 5:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])
                    elif target_object == 6:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.5, 1.0, 0.5]])
                    elif target_object == 7:
                        colors = tf.constant([[1.0, 0.5, 0.5]])
                    elif target_object == 8:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.5, 0.5, 1.0]])
                    elif target_object == 9:
                        colors = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
                    else:
                        colors = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
                    
                    image_cropped = tf.image.draw_bounding_boxes(tf.constant(image_cropped, shape=(1, IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1], IMAGE_SIZE[2]), dtype=tf.float32), boxes_custom_input, colors)
                    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array( tf.squeeze(image_cropped) *  255.0 )
    
    if b_training_object_detection :
    
        list_input_data = tf.cast( list_input_data, dtype=tf.float32 )
        list_label = tf.cast( list_label, dtype=tf.float32 )
        
        dataset_object_detection = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(list_input_data, shape=(1, len(list_input_data), 21, 21, 3), dtype=tf.float32), 
                tf.constant(list_label, shape=(1, len(list_label), 1), dtype=tf.float32)))
                
        history = model.fit( dataset_object_detection, batch_size=500, epochs=1, callbacks=[custom_callback] )
        model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)
    
    
    ###################################################################################
    # image_cropped = image_target_number( image_cropped, object_position ) 
    ###################################################################################

    image_cropped = tf.constant( image_cropped, shape=IMAGE_SIZE )
    image_cropped = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img( image_cropped )
    
    list_input_data = list_input_data[-100:,-2100:,-2100:,-300:]
    list_position_data = list_position_data[-100:,-300:]
    list_label = list_label[-100:,-100:]
    
    return image_cropped, object_count, "{:.2f}".format( tf.math.argmax( prediction_scores ).numpy() ), list_label, list_position_data
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, very sorry as a beginner in programming, I having problem to run your code. Can you show how to run it? I been using command search_screen("/content/models/research/object_detection/test_images/image1.jpg") and its not working in google colab. Sorry for my bad english also, I actually expected output image to shown template like in this https://github.com/darpan-jain/crowd-counting-using-tensorflow . Is your code outputting the similar format as from your output images, I cannot recognize it.

Comment: For my question, is there a simpler solution? For the code above, I already get the number of bounding boxes that have treshold of more than 0.5. I just need to print this value in image, currently I am using cv2.puttext but this is double job as i need to save the image and open it again to put text since I don't know how to modify the original code to become a single task (putting bounding boxes and display total number at same time). This the code I am using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Sry for late reply and thanks for your time, actually the below code is just what I am looking for, save the file somewhere then use CV2.puttext to display the number of counts. Regardless, please show me how to run your code, I'm interested to learn your approach.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will add a column of text to the existing google colab API and display the number of people just like this in this example  [Number of people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRUGT.png)

```
 def show_inference(model, image_path):
 global count
 count=0
 # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order 
 #to prepare the result image with boxes and labels on it.
 image_np = np.array(Image.open(image_path))
 # Actual detection.

 output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)
 # Visualization of the results of a detection.
 vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
  image_np,
  output_dict['detection_boxes'],
  output_dict['detection_classes'],
  output_dict['detection_scores'],
  category_index,
  instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
  line_thickness=8)

 img=Image.fromarray(image_np)

 img.save('/content/my_pig.png')

 for o in output_dict['detection_scores']:
 if o > 0.5:
 count=count+1  


 im=cv2.imread("/content/my_pig.png")
 im = cv2.putText(im, 'Number of people'+str(count), (50, 50), 
 cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
 cv2_imshow(im)
```

Comment: - The old question told want to display number on boxes created.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Jirayu, my bad maybe I should have say how to modify the code in google colab object detection API https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb to display number of box, do you realize this code actually is adapted from google object detection API? I have edited my question to make it more clear.